# What does the phrase "I think so" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, american-english

I asked the following question:

> Do all English language schools in your city believe that all people can learn English if they want to?

He replied:

> I think so.

What does that phrase "I think so" mean? How is it different from the answer "Yes"?

Comment: This question is asking the meaning of *so*.

Comment: It means that the answerer *believes* the answer is yes but doesn't *know* the answer is yes. The answerer apparently feels confident in his or her knowledge to draw a conclusion, one that is an opinion, an educated guess, but not confident enough in his or her knowledge to be certain of that conclusion, so the answerer is expressing the answer as an opinion rather than a fact. "I think so" is a yes that the answerer can't be held to, a yes that doesn't make the answerer a liar if the actual answer turns out to be no.

Answer (score 1):

It means the answerer think "YES" but he/she is not sure if his/her thought is the correct answer to the question in general. He/She is just expressing his/her yes to the question but it is kind of not answering as a fact or others belief